# Sorting a linked list in ascending and decending order

Tags: c#, sorting, linked-list

I have a generic linked list, currently made up of ints, and I want to sort them by ascending order by default, and then switch a boolean to sort them by descending values. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your linked list implements `IEnumerable<T>` (which it probably should!), you can just use the LINQ functions `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending`.

For ints, the default comparer is fine, so you would just write:

```
bool ascending = true;
var orderedEnumerable = ascending ? collection.OrderBy(x => x) : collection.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

Or, with a function and default args:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<int> GetOrderedNumbers(bool ascending = true)
{
      return ascending ? collection.OrderBy(x => x) : collection.OrderByDescending(x => x);
}
```

MSDN for OrderBy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and I would never have thought of this solution personally.  Despite linked lists being enumerable (by definition), I wouldn't have made the (glaringly obvious) connection between the IEnumerable interface and linked lists.  Kudos to you, sir!

Comment: Is there an alternative to this which doesn't use IEnumerable?

Comment: @user3113376 Well of course you can roll your own ordering algorithm (pick your favorite, quick sort, merge sort, heap sort, whatever). LINQ only works on `IEnumerable` though, and implementing it is basically just implementing the Iterator pattern. Its probably worth going down that route, as it allows you to use LINQ, `foreach` and deferred enumeration. I don't know of any other "baked in" functions that will do this if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the .NET's `LinkedList<T>` that, in its turn, implements `IEnumerable<T>` you can use some of these solutions:

This extension method returns a sorted copy of type `LinkedList<T>`

```
public static LinkedList<TSource> SortedAscending<TSource, TKey>(
    this LinkedList<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    LinkedList<TSource> tempLinkedList = new LinkedList<TSource>();
    IEnumerable<TSource> orderedEnumerable = source.OrderBy(keySelector).AsEnumerable();
    orderedEnumerable.ForEach(value => tempLinkedList.AddLast(value));
    return tempLinkedList;
}
```

This extension method sorts the source of type `LinkedList<T>`

```
public static void SelfSortAscending<TSource, TKey>(
    this LinkedList<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    LinkedList<TSource> tempLinkedList = new LinkedList<TSource>(source);
    source.Clear();
    IEnumerable<TSource> orderedEnumerable = tempLinkedList.OrderBy(keySelector).AsEnumerable();
    orderedEnumerable.ForEach(value => source.AddLast(value));
}
```

Extension methods for **descending** ordering you can find at:
[LinkedListHelper  (GitHub link)](https://github.com/AlexMelw/EasySharp/blob/master/NHelpers/Collections/Extensions/LinkedListExtensions.cs)

By the way, `.ForEach()` you could implement like this:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    if (action == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));

    foreach (T element in source)
        action(element);
}
```